# python syntax error with the version 2.5 any idea how to fix it?

Tags: python

first i tried to run it by pressing F5. it said the syntax error is in the first line. i tried running the program from the command line but it said the same thing. any idea what's wrong or how to fix it ?

[image: hello.py]

Comment: post your whole hello.py, pls

Comment: @Hamlett the link is a picture of the file content... It looks like copy/paste of a shell screen...

Comment: it doesn't makes too much sense to me... it looks fine... may be codification problems??

Comment: @Hamlett But it's not a python shell... It's a file.

Comment: Aw, sorry, it seems to be normal since the answer of @chepner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F5 runs the script in the current window, but the current window doesn't display a script: it displays an interactive interpreter (also known as a REPL: Read, Evaluate, Print Loop).

In this window, you simply type valid Python statements, and they execute immediately. There is not way, or need, to run the contents of the window.